# What is the best way to store user notifications in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a noticeboard module in a php/mysql app.  The idea is an admin can post notices to a single user, groups of users (by role), perhaps combinations of users/groups/roles, everyone in the system.

My initial thoughts were to have the following schema which solves my send to a single user or single user role:

```
notices
----------------
notice_id
notice_date
notice_title
notice_text
notice_recipients  <-- linked to user_role_id (from user_roles table)
```

I'm not sure how to record 2 groups and/or 50 individual recipients without having duplicated rows in the database.  Is it possible to store all the *user_role_id*'s in the one *notice_recipients* field and then somehow read the contents of that field to display in each individual users noticeboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a join table:

```
notices
----------------
notice_id
notice_date
notice_title
notice_text
```

and

```
notices_users
----------------
notice_id
user_id
```

When you create a notice, write it to the notces table. Then for every user, that should receive it, add a row to notices_users. If you have shown it, either delete it from notices_users or add a status field.

Comment: How does that work if I want to send a notice to a whole user_role?  Eg. Send to all admins.  Would that mean I have to get user_role then check who belongs to that role then insert a record for each user? which with some groups is over 1000 records.

Comment: Yes, this is necessary: You want to show the notice exactly once to every **user**, not to every **role**. So you need to dereference the group to make this information available. This is a single statement: `INSERT INTO notices_users SELECT ($noticeid, user_id) FROM users_roles WHERE role_id=$roleid` or similar should suffice and be quite fast.

Comment: Ok so if from a form an admin was to choose 2 individual users and a whole user group that would need your statement and another for the individual user_id right?

Comment: Exactly. You must also make sure, that no user is included twice - e.g. once as an admin, once as a manager. The main point is: Notifications go **per user**, no matter how often and why they were chosen.